# Insertar un elemento a un archivo xml con python

Tags: python

Estoy intentado añadir un elemento hijo a un elemento en Python. Mi idea es que el programa busque en el xml los elementos que les falte cierto subelemento, y a raíz de esto inserte uno genérico. Pongo ejemplo:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

En este xml, por ejemplo vemos que en el elemento del medio (Singapur) falta el subelemento year, por lo que mi código dbería de meter la entrada year.
Soy novato con Python, pero creo que esto se debería hacer con una estructura de repetición básica mi idea es meter en una lista todos los countrys (elemento padre) y que después a raiz de esta lista con un if seleccione aquellos donde falte el subelemento year y lo agregue con la función específica de la librería ElementTree... Pero no se si esto se podría hacer de alguna manera más rápida...
Muchas gracias y disculpad si he posteado mal ya que es mi primera entrada.
Saludos!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que te des una vuelta por [este manual](https://sodocumentation.net/es/python/topic/479/manipulando-xml) de manejo de XML con python, es muy sencillo, ahí está la respuesta que quieres.

Comment: Esta respuesta esta siendo considerada como de baja calidad por la comunidad. Aunque en el enlace pueda resolver la pregunta del OP, si el enlace cayera en algun momento la respuesta quedaría sin contenido. Para solucionar esto, deberías copiar en tu respuesta la parte mas relevante de la pagina enlazada que aplica a la pregunta planteada. Te recomiendo leer [Te he votado negativamente porque solamente pusiste un link.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2883/).

Comment: Agrega la información esencial del enlace por favor , revisar [answer].